# First form values get lost if the input unmounts in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have one form split into two part forms. The first form takes firstName, lastName and profilePhoto. The second form takes email, password, confirmPassword etc. When the user fills the first form and clicks the next button, the values in the first form do not stay in the form state. I have set the `shouldUnregister` to false as mentioned in the react-hook-form docs. But that doesn't seem to solve my problem.

```jsx
//hooks.ts


 const defaultRegisterValues = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            institution: "",
            regNo: "",
            department: "",
            profilePhoto: "",
        };

        const {
            register,
            handleSubmit,
            watch,
            getValues,
            formState: { errors: formErrors },
        } = useForm<RegisterFormInputs>({
            defaultValues: defaultRegisterValues,
            shouldFocusError: true,
            shouldUnregister: false,
        });

        const watchFields = watch();
        console.log("fields", watchFields);

        const emailRegister = register("email", {
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
            maxLength: 50,
        });
        const passwordRegister = register("password", {
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
            maxLength: 50,
        });
        const confirmPasswordRegister = register("confirmPassword", {
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
            maxLength: 50,
            validate: value => value === watch("password") || "Passwords do not match",
        });
        const firstNameRegister = register("firstName", {
            required: true,
            maxLength: 50,
        });
        const lastNameRegister = register("lastName", {
            maxLength: 50,
        });

        const institutionRegister = register("institution", {
            required: true,
        });

        const departmentRegister = register("department", {
            required: true,
        });
        const regNoRegister = register("regNo", {
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
            maxLength: 15,
        });
        const profilePhotoRegister = register("profilePhoto", {
            required: true,
        });

        const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data: RegisterFormInputs) => {
            console.log("submitting");
            console.log("Creating user...", data);
        });
      
      //FirstForm.tsx
      const { firstNameRegister, lastNameRegister, profilePhotoRegister, errors, getValues } = useRegister();
        return (
            <Slide
                direction="left"
                in={!isOpen}
                style={{ zIndex: 5, width: "30vw", position: "relative" }}
                unmountOnExit={true}
            >
                <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.profilePhoto} isRequired>
                    <FileUpload accept={"image/*"} multiple={false} register={profilePhotoRegister}>
                        <IconButton
                            aria-label="Profile Photo"
                            icon={<AvatarPlaceholder boxSize={120} />}
                            isRound
                            boxSize={120}
                            style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}
                        />
                    </FileUpload>
                    <FormErrorMessage>{errors.profilePhoto && errors.profilePhoto}</FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
                <RegisterFieldContainer>
                    <FormControl id="firstName" isInvalid={!!errors.firstName}>
                        <FormLabel>First Name</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={firstNameRegister?.name}
                            type="text"
                            ref={firstNameRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={firstNameRegister?.onChange}
                            defaultValue={getValues("firstName")}
                        />
                        <FormErrorMessage>{errors.firstName}</FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl id="lastName" isInvalid={!!errors.lastName}>
                        <FormLabel>Last Name</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={lastNameRegister?.name}
                            type="text"
                            ref={lastNameRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={lastNameRegister?.onChange}
                            defaultValue={getValues("lastName")}
                        />
                        <FormErrorMessage>{errors.lastName}</FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>
                </RegisterFieldContainer>
                <Center>
                    <IconButton
                        variant="solid"
                        aria-label="forward"
                        icon={<ArrowForwardIcon boxSize={10} />}
                        isRound
                        boxSize={16}
                        marginTop={10}
                        onClick={onToggle}
                    />
                </Center>
            </Slide>
        
        
        // SecondForm.tsx
        const {
            emailRegister,
            passwordRegister,
            confirmPasswordRegister,
            regNoRegister,
            institutionRegister,
            departmentRegister,
            errors,
        } = useRegister();
        return (
            <Slide
                in={isOpen}
                unmountOnExit={true}
                direction="right"
                style={{ zIndex: zIdxValue, width: "30vw", position: "relative" }}
            >
                <RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                    <FormControl id="email">
                        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                        <Input name={emailRegister?.name} type="email" ref={emailRegister?.ref} onChange={emailRegister?.onChange} />
                        {errors.email && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.email}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl id="regNo">
                        <FormLabel>Registration Number</FormLabel>
                        <Input name={regNoRegister?.name} type="text" ref={regNoRegister?.ref} onChange={regNoRegister?.onChange} />
                        {errors.regNo && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.regNo}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                </RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                <RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                    <FormControl id="password">
                        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={passwordRegister?.name}
                            type="password"
                            ref={passwordRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={passwordRegister?.onChange}
                        />
                        {errors.password && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.password}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl id="confirmPassword">
                        <FormLabel>Confirm Password</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={confirmPasswordRegister?.name}
                            type="password"
                            ref={confirmPasswordRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={confirmPasswordRegister?.onChange}
                        />
                        {errors.confirmPassword && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.confirmPassword}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                </RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                <RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                    <FormControl id="institution">
                        <FormLabel>Institution</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={institutionRegister?.name}
                            type="text"
                            ref={institutionRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={institutionRegister?.onChange}
                        />
                        {errors.institution && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.institution}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl id="department">
                        <FormLabel>Department</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name={departmentRegister?.name}
                            type="text"
                            ref={departmentRegister?.ref}
                            onChange={departmentRegister?.onChange}
                        />
                        {errors.department && <FormErrorMessage>{errors.department}</FormErrorMessage>}
                    </FormControl>
                </RegisterFieldSubContainer>
                <Flex flexDirection="row" alignItems="baseline" width="100%" justifyContent="space-between">
                    <Button variant="link" onClick={onToggle} marginTop="2em">
                        Back
                    </Button>
                    <RegisterButton type="submit" variant="solid" marginTop="2em" width="45%">
                        Register
                    </RegisterButton>
                </Flex>
            </Slide>
      
      //index.tsx (the one that renders both forms
      const { handleSubmit } = useRegister();
        return (
            <RegisterContainer>
                <RegisterFormContainer>
                    <Heading>Register</Heading>
                    <RegisterForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <FirstForm isOpen={isOpen} onToggle={onToggle} />
                        <SecondForm isOpen={isOpen} onToggle={onToggle} />
                    </RegisterForm>
                    {!isOpen && <Link href="/login">Already have an account? Login</Link>}
                </RegisterFormContainer>
            </RegisterContainer>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got two separate components and import and instantiate `useRegister()` in each of them. That way you've got two separate form states.

I'd propose you to make a common parent for those two components. Instantiate `useRegister()` there once and pass desctructured props to the current step's form.

Comment: I have done the same thing. There is a parent component for the FirstForm and SecondForm. The issue is when I click to go to the next form the first form has to unmount. Which causes the values to disappear.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at stackblitz.com or codesandbox.io?